# How to get command line of UNIX process?

Tags: mac, command-line, unix, process

Is it possible to grab the command line that was used to invoke a process on Mac OS X?

Comment: `ps --pid $PID -o args=` That's what I use, anyway...

Comment: The Mac equivalent of that command is: `ps -p <pid> -o args=`

Comment: if "-o args=" truncates the output, you can try `ps -p <pid> -o command=`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ps ax` shows you the command line of all running processes; you can grep for the pid you want.

Comment: @mark4o Or simply ps awux | cat, as ps -w will not limit the number of columns to display when output is not stdout, such as when piped to another command.

Comment: Why does this happen every week? "Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html" and "Note that "ps -aux" is distinct from "ps aux". The POSIX and UNIX standards require that "ps -aux" print all processes owned by a user named "x", as well as printing all processes that would be selected by the -a option. If the user named "x" does not exist, this ps may interpret the command as "ps aux" instead and print a warning. This behavior is intended to aid in transitioning old scripts and habits. It is fragile, subject to change, and thus should not be relied upon."

Comment: I don't know, Hello71. I corrected my two-year-old answer for you.

Answer (score 4):

Does:

```
~$ ps ax | grep "ntp"
   57   ??  Ss     0:04.66 /usr/sbin/ntpd -c /private/etc/ntp.conf -n
 3104 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep ntp
```

do what you need it to (change ntp to the program you are interested in)? This usually gives me the command-line arguments of running processes (I use to check what Launchd used when running a system daemon for example).

Answer (score 3):

`cat /proc/$PROCESSNUMBER/cmdline | tr '\0' '\n'`

Allthough it's Linux specific, it gets the commandline of process numbered `$PROCESSNUMBER` straight from the kernel (the `/proc/$PROCESSNUMBER/cmdline` part) and makes it readable by putting each argument on a separate line by translating (with `tr -token` replace) the \0's into newlines (\n).

This line only works if you put a real processnumber of a running process (you can find one by running the command `ps -ef`) in the $PROCESSNUMBER part!

Comment: The original poster asked for Mac OS X (which out of the box does not have `procfs`)

Comment: Or `xargs -0 < /proc/PID/cmdline`